# Why is there ffmpeg codec noise when encoding test tone?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I used FFmpeg to generate a test clip with color bars and a tone. I also made a special filter to dump out the raw audio data to check it. I was surprised to find that there is significant noise riding on the audio tone after it has gone through the AAC codec. Is this expected? Is there a way to prevent it?

To make the test file I used:

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "smptehdbars=duration=600:size=1280x720:rate=59.94" -qscale:v 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p smpte_r59_720.mp4

then

ffmpeg -i  smpte_r59_720.mp4 -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:sample_rate=48000:duration=600" -qscale:v 1 -vcodec copy -c:a aac -b:a 192k  -shortest -map 0:0 -map 1:0 smpte_r59_720T.mp4

and then

ffmpeg -i smpte_r59_720T.mp4 -y -map 0 -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb smpte_r59_720T.ts

(Trying to do this all in one step kept failing.)

Other variations on this have varying degrees of noise, sometimes above nominal amplitude and sometimes below.

After finding this problem I pulled a third party test tone .WAV file with 44.1KHz sample rate from the web and checked it. The raw file is clean, but the encoded file I made has noise.

[Noise on TS SMPTE bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDMiu.png)

[Clean audio from MP4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BWYF.png)

Comment: Don't get any noise here. How's the single step command failing?

Comment: I no longer have the command line I used for that, but it was generating unplayable garbage. That, however, is a side issue. If the codec is creating noise, it will be much harder to tell if my custom filters are working. If you are not seeing any noise, maybe I will go back and try a stock copy of FFmpeg in case the minor changes I have made to add filters has somehow trashed something.

Comment: If in doubt, update your `ffmpeg` to a current build.